# All-in-one solution for using OAuth2 with Compojure

Tags: clojure, oauth-2.0, social-networking, compojure

I am trying to integrate a compojure application with those OAuth2 providers: LinkedIn, Facebook, Google, and Twitter, using an all in one solution. I am aware of some existing java libraries such as scribe-java or spring-social that can help. But they suck when used from clojure. Is there a more clojure friendly solution to my goal? Or can anyone point me to a working sample / tutorial on how to reach my goal?

Answer (score 4):

For OAuth 2.0, there's https://github.com/DerGuteMoritz/clj-oauth2

<strike>Disclaimer: I haven't tried it, but I'm just about to. I'll come back and report on my experiences, and if I get a sample app up on GitHub.</strike>

OK - I can report that clj-oauth2, while lacking in documentation, does actually work. [I submitted a pull request for OAuth 2.0 Draft 10 support](https://github.com/DerGuteMoritz/clj-oauth2/pull/6) (required for use with Force.com, and probably Google, too). I'll also post an example app sometime soon to my fork at https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/clj-oauth2

Comment: How was it? Did you find it easy to use? My experiences using oauth2 libs in ruby and javascript have been atrocious.

Comment: Well, it was version 0.2.0, so my expectations were not high. Documentation - almost non-existent, so I had to read the source quite a bit to get it working successfully, and make a few changes to get it to support salesforce.com's OAuth 2.0 Draft 10 implementation. I have a sample app that I'll post to my GitHub repo soon https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc

Comment: Does clj-oauth2 work for Twitter? I can't figure out if Twitter supports OAuth 2 or not, despite conflicting token URLs.

Comment: Twitter supports OAuth 2.0 for [Application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) only; OAuth 1.0a is still required to issue requests on behalf of users.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/mattrepl/clj-oauth

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this one, I just found it in [clojure-libraries](http://clojure-libraries.appspot.com/).

Comment: How does this compare to `clj-oauth2`?

Comment: clj-oauth does not support OAuth 2.